# How can I find out the number of Google search results for a query?

Tags: google-search, autocorrect

I'm not a native English speaker, so whenever I type a sentence I always wonder if it is correct or informal use. My current approach is to input the sentence in Google Search and see how many results there are.

For example, if I'm wondering whether it is correct to write "have a question for my friend" or "have a question to my friend", I can easily determine this with Google by doing a search (note the quotes).

However this is quite inconvenient. So, how can I find out how many results there are from Google Search, instantly for whatever I type? Getting the autocorrections would also be nice…

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's inconvenient about using Google itself? It shows the number of results.

Comment: @Nano8Blazex : Let's image I have to open a browser than paste everything I typed to google everytime ...

Comment: Wouldn't it be similar with some kind of software? You'd still have to launch the application, and paste in...

Comment: I think you're not looking for a software to show you Google results, but rather software or web-apps to find out whether you're correct or not.

Comment: @Nano8Blazex : No. I'm looking for some softwares that can tell me how many results there are from Google Search instantly for whatever I type. It doesn't require copy-paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Google Fight](http://www.googlefight.com/). It does the searches at the same time and gives you the numbers you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks, but anyway I'm looking for a software can automatically correct my vocabulary and grammar whenever and wherever I type.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem learning Francais. I found [BonPatron](http://bonpatron.com/en/). They have an English version, [SpellCheckPlus](http://spellcheckplus.com/), which works for English grammar. It is probably a better judge of proper English than the number of Google results. It will tell you exactly what is wrong with your sentence, so that next time you will know. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Senoculus, I tried SpellCheckPlus and found it didn't meet my situation. I need a software to catch my every words and automatically correct my vocabulary and grammar. (As I said I think it can be done with google search service integrated). Thanks anyway :)